JupyterLab custom extension where if i click on button or link to existing notebooks in voila preview should open in split tab to the right
I want to create a custom extension where if any link/button to notebooks in voila preview should open the notebook in voila preview in split tab with jupyterlab.
I am new to JupyterLab extensions , even if not through extension any other approach is fine . Really appreciate your help on this
Lets say i have a small code in jupyter notebook cell
from IPython.display import display, HTML

# Create an HTML link that opens the notebook in Voilà preview
html_link = """
<a href="untitled1.ipynb" >Open other notebook with Voilà</a>
"""
display(HTML(html_link))


Which after rendering with voila preview looks like this
on voila Preview
The way on clicking "Render with voila" toolbar button it splits the window into two the same way if i click on the notebook link it should provide rendered view split to the right
The required way
Right now by default it renders with voila  in new browser tab altogether but i want to split to right within jupyter lab tab(mdde : split-right)
I have added in jupyter discourse as well
https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-custom-extension-where-if-i-click-on-button-or-link-to-existing-notebooks-in-voila-preview-should-open-in-split-tab-to-the-right/28519

I have added @Wayne

Thanks. Perhaps, fix it to read better? Maybe [related post at Jupyter Discourse Forum] & then link in parentheses? Or at least 'I have posted here as well', like you had at other site? Right now, it just says 'Edit:', followed by a link.
